# SQL Server SPID stuck on runnable with nothing blocking

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server SPID that is running a query with a status of "runnable".  I can see the CPUTime and DiskIO slowly increasing over time.  There are no blocks and no waits when using sp_who2 and `sp_whoisactive`. The query usually takes 5 minutes to complete but is taking what seems like forever. Any ideas on why this is taking so long?

Comment: try to run the query in ssms and enable live execution plan , and monitor the execution plan to find out where the battle neck is . or simply

Comment: By the way you're phrasing it, you're seeing snapshots of the process status. Each time you look it's in runnable but it could be going into running, waiting, and back to runnable while you're doing that. I'd set up a briefly running extended events session for wait_completed for your session and see what pops up. Note the "brief" part - I think that particular XE is pretty expensive to gather so don't leave it on.

Comment: Please share the query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/